# Python -- Function with a Pandas dataframe as an argument

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, anaconda

I have to create a function that takes a Pandas dataframe as an argument and returns a copy of the dataframe after replacing the null values in each column with the most frequent value in the column.

Cannot use **FOR** or **WHILE** loops.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to create a copy you can simply use `df.copy(deep = True)` (note that deep = True creates a new dataframe-object, otherwise you get a reference to the copied dataframe).
To replace the null values with the most frequent values, you can use the *mode* method for Series and DataFrames (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html).

An example would be:
`df = df.fillna(df.mode().iloc[0])`